# Have EF automatically resend queries after various errors

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-5

When I execute a command against a redundant SQL configuration (such as SQL Azure), I sometimes get timeouts and other misc. errors that are due to a server being shutdown or failing.  On Azure this isn't a problem, since redundancy is built-in.  The correct action is to re-attempt the query with a new connection, and most likely the load balancers (or whatever) will kick you over to a server that's functioning properly.

My question is whether there is a way to have Entity Framework (v4 or v5) do this automatically?  Wrapping every query with a try/catch block (that reattempts the query if certain errors are received) is impractically, and I feel confident that there's a solution to this problem that I'm overlooking.

For related information about SQL Azure's random closing of connections, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx#cc.  However, as of late, I have not gotten this error from Azure at all... I just got the occasional, sporadic SQL timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the Transient Fault Handling Framework from SQL CAT :

http://windowsazurecat.com/2010/12/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling/

=== Added by @pbarranis ===

According to that same site, but a different page:

> The Transient Fault Handling Framework has been superseded by a newer
>   deliverable from the Patterns & Practices team. It is now called the
>   Transient Fault Handling Application Block and comes in all 3 flavors:
>
> •Developer guidance:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=PandP.50).aspx
>
> •NuGet package:
>   http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling
>
> •Source code:
>   http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Source.WindowsAzure
>
> The new Transient Fault Handling Application Block is now our
>   officially recommended approach to handling transient faults in the
>   applications running on the Windows Azure platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework 6 (currently in alpha) then there is some new in-built support for transient retries with Azure SQL Database (with a little bit of configuration): http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec

I've created a library which allows you to configure Entity Framework to retry using the Fault Handling block without needing to change every database call - generally you will only need to change your config file and possibly one or two lines of code.

This allows you to use it for Entity Framework or Linq To Sql.

https://github.com/robdmoore/ReliableDbProvider